# change folder icons in ubuntu-mono-dark theme

Tags: unity, themes, icons, nemo

I'm running 13.10 with Unity, and I have a "problem":

I'm using Nemo, because I prefer it over Nautilus (for obvious reasons imo), and it works really great.

The drawback of Nemo is, that it is kind of ugly; so I want to change the Icons of the folders. That's not a problem at all, using unity-tweak-tool, to change for example to one of the icon-themes which are delivered by [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/icons).

The thing is, although this works great, and the Icons change, the problem is, that all of the Icons change, including my applications in the tray, and application icons in the dash. Can I modify the theme in such a way, that only the Icons for the folders change, and nothing else?

So e.g. delete everything in the `~/.icon/<theme-name>/` folder except `places` and "inherit" everything else from the default ubuntu-mono-dark theme?

Comment: Nemo simply uses the icons present in the GTK theme you are using. And that's pretty much the goal: to have the same visual semantics across the whole desktop environment. If you find it ugly why don't you try changing the GTK theme? In principle, to use a custom icon set, Nemo should have to be reprogrammed or extended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, from the theme you installed, copy these 55 icons into the Humanity theme:

```
folder-copy
folder-remote-symbolic
folder-ubuntu
folder_download
folder-pictures-symbolic
folder-system
gnome-folder
folder-home
folder-move
folder-music
folder-music-symbolic
folder-visiting
folder_open
folder_tar
folder-drag-accept
folder-documents-symbolic
folder-symbolic
folder-remote-ssh
folder-publicshare-symbolic
folder-downloads
folder-remote
stock_folder
folder-remote-smb
folder-download-symbolic
folder_images
folder-open
folder
folders-publicshare
stock_folder-properties
folder-templates-symbolic
folders-music
stock_folder-copy
folder-publicshare
folder-saved-search
folders-downloads
folder-documents
stock_folder-move
stock_folder_properties
folder-videos-symbolic
folder-remote-nfs
folder-pictures
folder-remote-ftp
folder-video
folder-templates
folder_new
folder-new
folder_pictures
folder-recent
folders-documents
folder-images
folder_home
folder-saved-search-symbolic
add-folder-to-archive
folder-videos
folder-download
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I discovered that it is better to create a custom theme with exactly the files you described, and add to the `index.theme: Inherits=ubuntu-mono-dark` (or whichever theme you're using. So the original themes are not altered